# In processing, how can one translate to a final coordinate in world space?

Tags: processing

One can translate by x and y distances in processing relative to the frame of reference with the `translate()` function.

Is there a function that one can use to translate to an absolute coordinate in world space? For instance, can one translate to the coordinate (20, 30) relative to the window regardless of where your frame of reference has previously translated to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use translate for the first time in your code, you're actually translating the whole coordinate system. If you want to draw an object at a position/transformation independently (without) affecting following transformations, you should isolate that within [pushMatrix()](http://processing.org/reference/pushMatrix_.html)/popMatrix() calls.

here's a v. basic example:

```
pushMatrix();
translate(50,50);
rect(0,0,50,50);
popMatrix();

translate(20,20);
rect(0,0,20,20);
```

The big square(50x50) is drawn first at position 50,50, but the translation is isolated between `pushMatrix()/popMatrix()` calls, so when we call `translate(20,20)` a translation will be performed from 0,0, not from 50,50 which means we get a small box drawn at 20,20, not 70,70.

Comment: Thanks, I'll just push/pop the matrix stack to keep track of the coordinate system.